# How to view the Oracle view history?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to view the Oracle view history? I would like to know who created the Oracle view and by who this view was modified (all view changes).

Comment: That is not possible until n unless there is a database level trigger already in place in your system.

Comment: May [the post](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35840/what-queries-is-oracle-executing-how-frequently-and-time-taken) or using [auto trace](http://betteratoracle.com/posts/10-using-autotrace) will help you.